# AngularJS controller not showing data from database in routed view

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to get one of my routed pages to load data from a MySQL database.  After looking online at a few different tutorials, I seem to be doing something wrong and can't figure out why it's not working.

**INDEX PAGE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/angtest/">
        <title>AngularJS Test</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <p>
            <a href="home">Home</a> - <a href="about">About</a> - <a href="items">Items</a>
            <br>
            Click on the links to go to new pages.
        </p>
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.7/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
            app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
            function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
                .when("/", {
                    templateUrl : "home.html"
                }).when("/home", {
                    redirectTo : "/"
                }).when("/about", {
                    templateUrl : "about.html"
                }).when("/items", {
                    templateUrl : "items.html",
                    controller : "usercontroller"
                }).otherwise({
                    redirectTo : "/"
                });
            }]);
            app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){
                $http.get("select.php")
                .then(function(data){
                    $scope.items = data;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When going to /home, /about or /items, the pages load correctly, but /items isn't grabbing the database information.

Title and description are the columns from the items table I would like shown.

**ITEMS PAGE:**

```
<h1>MySQL Database</h1>
<div ng-controller="usercontroller">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
            <td>{{ x.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.description }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**SELECT SCRIPT:**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DBNAME");
    $output = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM items";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

In the console window, no errors show up.

**UPDATE**

To check the console window, I changed my controller to:

```
app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("select.php")
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.items = data;
    });
});
```

The log is showing:

[image: Console Window]

Comment: From the partial code you posted, it is not clear what is happening in the user controller/component that is suppse to be responsible to dispatch the ajax request to get the items from the server and populate the `items` scope variable to be used in the ng-repeat. What is the usercontroller code?

Comment: The controller code is in the index page, which was posted above.  From tutorials I found online, it's using function with $scope and $http, where the items should be defined through .get.

Comment: my bad, i did not see that one. Two suggestions. 1. In the developer toos, do you see the ajax request get sent and given the right 200 status with data response? 2. When debugging or putting console.log before the $scope.items = data, whats info does the data holds? is the code get there or the response promise get regected? Maybe the response is angularjs http  response which you need to extact the data from that object.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I'll take a look and get back to you!

Comment: I updated my question after adding in console logging.  Let me know if that helps any.  The data seems to be reading, but it's not actually showing?

Comment: you get angularjs $http response. The real server data is in the `data` property. Meaning you need to do `scope.items = data.data`. Or for bravity `then(function(resp) { scope.data = resp.data }`

Comment: Thank you!  Worked like a charm!  Would you be able to point me in the right direction of being able to change it up slightly to allow me to do something along the lines of /item/#, so I can show only that item?

Comment: It's the same principle as the table controller. different ui route, When the item controller start, you need to send ajax request like you do now to a different server endpoint that will return only the request db item as a result.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Item page**

```
<h1>MySQL Database</h1> <div> <table> <tr> <th>Item Name</th> <th>Item Description</th> </tr> <tr ng-repeat="x in items"> <td>{{ x.title }}</td> <td>{{ x.description }}</td> </tr> </table> </div>
```